# Typescript - peculiar error message upon variable assignment

Tags: typescript

I have this block of code:

```
survey = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(survey));
return Promise.all([
   app.models.survey_answers.findOne({surveyId: survey.id, coachDealerId: coachDealer.id, wave: wave}),
   app.models.survey_localizations.find({surveyId: survey.id})
   ]);
}).then(function(results){
answer = results[0];
```

For some reason, upon assignment to answer variable (last line in above code), I get following error:

> *message: "coachDealerId is not defined" stack: "ReferenceError: coachDealerId is not defined↵    at eval (eval at     at
>   ↵    at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"
>   **proto**: Error*

I have checked that coachDealerId is indeed defined in places where necessary.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet I want to find out why during the assignment to answer variable error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when data is queried from DB with a specific condition no data is returned hence the coachDealerId is undefined. This appears to be related to a data issue rather than code.